# Regex How to remove commas that aren't preceded or followed by alpha numeric Character?

Tags: c#, regex, string, replace, split

I've got a string of order numbers.  My requirements are:

1- Remove all non-alpha numeric characters except commas.

My issue, is that sometimes this can look like **"00023402,0234023,,023402034,,,23402034,**"
When it should look like **"00023402,0234023,023402034,23402034"** With no multiple commas, or commas at the end.

Here's what I'm currently doing

```
        var orderNumbers = parameters.OrderNumbers;
        var newsString = Regex.Replace(orderNumbers, "[^a-zA-Z0-9,]", "");
        List<string> orderNumbersRequest = newsString.Split(',').ToList();
```

this splits the new regex sanitized string by comma, making a list of strings. Currently orderNumbersRequest has a bunch of blank strings when multiple commas or a comma at the end is inputted.

I'm fairly new to regex, and not 100% sure how to **only include commas that have an alpha numeric character before or after them.**

Anyone know how to do this?

Comment: Use `Regex.Replace(orderNumbers, @"^,+|,+$|(,)+", "$1")`

Comment: `List<string> orderNumbersRequest = orderNumbers.Split(',', StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries).ToList();`

Comment: `string.Join(",",Regex.Matches(orderNumbers, @"\w+").Cast<Match>().Select(match => match.Value));`

Comment: ... or simply `string result = string.Join(",", Regex.Matches(input, @"\d+").OfType<Match>());`

Comment: Ok, it is `OfType` that is safer.